# How can I clear the animations associated with bones in 3DS Max 2009?

Tags: 3dsmax

I was given a model by an artist and it was boned and skinned for me. The .max file that he provided also included an animation to show what he would be able to do. (A basic running animation.)

However, this was the last I heard from him and I want to construct my own animation. I was wondering if there was any quick and easy way of removing the rotation animation on the bones, back to default values. (i.e., 0 on all axis or to the default biped positions.)

I have removed all the keyframes and the default pose seems to be the first frame of the animation that was created by the artist. I have tried setting the values in the X, Y, Z boxes at the bottom, nothing happens, I think its relative to the current position?

I have also tried setting the biped to figure mode, copying the pose and pasting the pose back to the original biped. That only seemed to work in bits and pieces, some of the bones didn't seem rotate, like the pelvis and the spine bones, and also after a while the bones seemed to revert back to the default running stance, or some bones would just take on a weird, random rotation.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know, but it sounds like the model looks pretty funny, any screen-caps you can share?

Comment: @another. I'm sure you've worked around it by now but just out of curiosity, when you delete the Skin modifier from the geometry, what pose does the model take? I am wondering whether your artist modelled the entity, skinned it, then without creating keyframes proceeded to modify the bone transforms. If this was the case then I believe it is akin to moving vertices around - i.e. once you save and discard the undo stack, there is no way back, but would be interested to know if there was!